# I'm importing my excel data(multiple sheets) but getting this error:

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Whenever there is blank entity in my excel file there is a problem occur in my program.

Before i was using this method and it was giving me error:

```
df.fillna('NA', inplace = True)
```

attributerror: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fillna'

But now i'm iterating over the values but getting this error:
TypeError: 'DataError' object is not subscriptable

Now im using this Logic:

```
for df in dfs.values():
    df.fillna('NA', inplace = True)
```

And my read_excel:

```
filename = input("Input the Filename: ")
dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None)

print (dfs.keys()) #print the name of sheets
```

Comment: What is your code also with `read` excel file?

Comment: I've edited this question can you lookout at it

Comment: there is no typo, `dfs.fillna('NA', inplace = True)` instead `df.fillna('NA', inplace = True)` ? Because `df` in code in question is `DataFrame`, `dfs` is dict.

Comment: Yes but that was before i was using dfs for a df method. But now i'm iterating over the values . Is there any possible way of using fillna method with dict object ?

Comment: No, you need processing `df` like in question. Cannot use `dfs.fillna`

Comment: Ok thankyou for help